In Interface builder, how do I minimize scrollview size with constraints?
I have my view controller and xib file. In the xib file, on the main view I have a subview. The subview contains a scrollview above a button. The scrollview's content view contains a text label and text view. The strings for the text label and text view are being sourced from a strings file. The second text for the text view may be sourced from one of several files and tends to have larger text but it varies. The text view is not scrollable. The button has it's height fixed.
What I want - The UIView containing the scroll view and button needs to grow or shrink based on the content of the scroll view, but the UIView containing everything also shouldn't grow bigger than the top and bottom constraints of the device screen. The scroll view should minimize its size to the size of the content view if possible. If the size of the two text labels (due to their string sizes) is large enough, then the scroll view should grow to match that size based on it's content view up to the size fitting in the UIView containing it and the button. Once the UIView containing the scroll view and the button has reached it's maximum size, the button should still be fixed at the bottom and the scroll view should take up the rest of the screen and at that point, it should become scrollable if the text is larger still.
I can do this programmatically. That's not much of an issue. I'm wanting to do this entirely through the xib and the interface builder and I'm not sure how to approach this with the constraint options given there. I've spent about 6 hours trying different things and I'm just not getting it. Any help?

This can be done -- but it's a bit convoluted. The trick is constraining the Height of the scroll view to the Height of the "content" view ... with various greater-than / less-than / different constraint priorities and content hugging priorities.
Very tough to write out all the steps, so here is a pic of the XIB:


system yellow is the View
pink is the scroll view
blue is the "content" view
yellow label
green text view

Here's the XIB view class, along with NibLoadable protocol and extension:
class TinyTimXIB: UIView, NibLoadable {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTV: UITextView!
    
    var numLines: Int = 0
    var nInc: Int = 2
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupFromNib()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupFromNib()
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
        print("did tap")
        
        numLines += nInc
        if numLines > 15 {
            nInc = -2
        } else if numLines < 4 {
            nInc = 2
        }
        let s = (2...numLines).compactMap( { "Line \($0)" } ).joined(separator: "\n")
        myTV.text = "UITextView\n" + s
        
        guard let btn = sender as? UIButton else { return }
        var cfg = btn.configuration
        var t: String = nInc > 0 ? "Add Lines" : "Remove Lines"
        t += " - Current: \(numLines)"
        cfg?.title = t
        btn.configuration = cfg
    }
}

public protocol NibLoadable {
    static var nibName: String { get }
}

public extension NibLoadable where Self: UIView {
    
    static var nibName: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self) // defaults to the name of the class implementing this protocol.
    }
    
    static var nib: UINib {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
        return UINib(nibName: Self.nibName, bundle: bundle)
    }
    
    func setupFromNib() {
        guard let view = Self.nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView else { fatalError("Error loading \(self) from nib") }
        addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}

Adding this as a subview in a view controller:

with 20-points padding on all 4 sides.
Each tap on the button will add a couple lines, until we get to 16 and then each tap will remove a couple lines. Once we get to 12 lines (on an iPhone 15 Pro), the scroll view stops growing and becomes scrollable:




Here's the source to the XIB file so you can use IB to inspect it:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="22154" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="22130"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="TinyTimXIB" customModule="scratch202401" customModuleProvider="target">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="myLabel" destination="ngF-8x-hAl" id="SfW-3V-ZsK"/>
                <outlet property="myTV" destination="3e6-OZ-aFR" id="K2o-YH-3In"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="NN7-sN-S8u">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="432" height="671"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Co8-1S-Ok1">
                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="28" width="416" height="252.5"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="k07-XG-JE8" userLabel="CView">
                            <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="376" height="212.5"/>
                            <subviews>
                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ngF-8x-hAl" userLabel="MyLabel">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="360" height="29"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                </label>
                                <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" scrollEnabled="NO" editable="NO" textAlignment="natural" selectable="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="3e6-OZ-aFR" userLabel="MyTV">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="45" width="360" height="159.5"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                    <string key="text">UITextView
Text will be dynamic...</string>
                                    <color key="textColor" systemColor="labelColor"/>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="40"/>
                                    <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                                </textView>
                            </subviews>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.46202266219999999" green="0.83828371759999998" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstItem="3e6-OZ-aFR" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ngF-8x-hAl" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="8q7-Qe-qqo"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="3e6-OZ-aFR" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ngF-8x-hAl" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="9xR-by-3kr"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="ngF-8x-hAl" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="k07-XG-JE8" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="fHY-O5-b28"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="3e6-OZ-aFR" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="k07-XG-JE8" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="kmr-Sg-lga"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="3e6-OZ-aFR" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="qSL-aL-gs3"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="ngF-8x-hAl" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="k07-XG-JE8" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="qh3-II-CX1"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="3e6-OZ-aFR" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="qjo-yL-8ID"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="ngF-8x-hAl" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="sDe-jO-WhS"/>
                            </constraints>
                        </view>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.79083781379999996" blue="0.99597025539999995" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" relation="lessThanOrEqual" secondItem="k07-XG-JE8" secondAttribute="height" constant="40" id="5LD-n0-Hd9"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="k07-XG-JE8" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="V8E-tM-mHa" secondAttribute="height" priority="250" constant="-40" id="CFn-Ik-QU0"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="k07-XG-JE8" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="jwi-97-yB3" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-20" id="PWZ-Mc-QtM"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="k07-XG-JE8" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="jwi-97-yB3" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="V1S-dA-dr2"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="k07-XG-JE8" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="V8E-tM-mHa" secondAttribute="width" constant="-40" id="d65-Os-mzF"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="k07-XG-JE8" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="jwi-97-yB3" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="gsd-cg-ISa"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="k07-XG-JE8" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="jwi-97-yB3" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="o4f-sM-k2h"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="jwi-97-yB3"/>
                    <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="V8E-tM-mHa"/>
                </scrollView>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0fT-vS-7VT" userLabel="AddLinesBtn">
                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="613" width="416" height="50"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="50" id="TU4-0f-Y8Z"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                    <buttonConfiguration key="configuration" style="filled" title="Add Lines"/>
                    <connections>
                        <action selector="didTap:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="ToM-EE-Sjz"/>
                    </connections>
                </button>
            </subviews>
            <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="JWK-TM-5X8"/>
            <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="0fT-vS-7VT" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Co8-1S-Ok1" secondAttribute="bottom" priority="750" constant="8" id="OBz-ja-4yF"/>
                <constraint firstItem="Co8-1S-Ok1" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="JWK-TM-5X8" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="ZFJ-F0-dou"/>
                <constraint firstItem="JWK-TM-5X8" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="0fT-vS-7VT" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="cIW-BW-3pC"/>
                <constraint firstItem="0fT-vS-7VT" firstAttribute="top" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="Co8-1S-Ok1" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="fA0-tw-Go1"/>
                <constraint firstItem="JWK-TM-5X8" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="0fT-vS-7VT" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="o37-Gn-NnO"/>
                <constraint firstItem="Co8-1S-Ok1" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="JWK-TM-5X8" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="oZC-Iy-oyX"/>
                <constraint firstItem="JWK-TM-5X8" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Co8-1S-Ok1" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="tcy-Gi-3g3"/>
                <constraint firstItem="0fT-vS-7VT" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="JWK-TM-5X8" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="zW4-Hf-Mdc"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="283.19999999999999" y="14.842578710644679"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="labelColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemYellowColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.80000000000000004" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>

